# parellelizing for loop in python

Tags: python, arrays

I am pretty new to python and i am yet to get a good handle on it.

I am dealing with huge datas in arrays and matrices, so i need some help in parellelizing the loops.

Heres my exact problem :

#Program Block starts

```
A= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
B= [2, 5, 7, 9, 15] 

# I have a 3*3 matrix

C = [[0 for x in range(3)] for x in range(3)]
C[0][:]=[2,5,7]
C[1][:]=[7,9,15]
C[2][:]=[2,9,15]

#C is composed of elements of the array B and i want to change each element which would correspond to A i.e. change 2 to 1 , 5 to 2, and so on.

C_new = []

for el in range(0, 3):
    n = C[el][:]
    n_new=[]
    for i in range(0, 3):
        for j in range(0,5):
            if  n[i]== B[j]:
                n_new.append(j+1)
    C_new.append(n_new)
```

`#Program Block Ends`

I will obtain an output of

```
C_new =[ 1 2 3; 3 4 5; 1 4 5]
```

My original sizes are as follows:

A & B have 600000

C has 4000000*4

so i would like to parallelize wrt the rows of C ..break down 4000000 into parts..

Comment: Look at [threading in python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html)

Comment: Your example code doesn't match the lists you have...please make sure your example can run

Comment: Sorry! i just wrote a pseudo code to explain the problem...  i shall try to edit with a working code.. Thanks

Comment: Where is ```C``` in your example code then ? I think you mean to say ```n=C[i]``` in line 1 of the for loop. You should take time to make sure your code is clear. Also, as I am sure you know,  you can run parallel code regardless of the size of the arrays, so you might as well remove the sizes from the question as that is seemingly irrelevant information

Comment: Yes, Sorry for that error. i guess now it works

Comment: And if I run your code, I get ```C_new = [[0], [], []]``` (after adding the ```:``` after the ```if``` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like this, I recommend you taking a look at Numpy. It's been built to work with large arrays such as this.

Comment: Much much faster than doing element-by-element manipulations in python though, as in question's code.

Comment: Thanks!..  

I changed the last three loops as  

flag=(A==B).astype(int)  


flag_ind=[i for i, e in enumerate(flag) if e==0]  

for x in flag_ind:  
     C_new[C_new==B[x]]=A[x]